# Including Laravel's app.scss File

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass

I'd like to use Bootstrap with Laravel 5.4.  According [to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend)

> The default webpack.mix.js included with Laravel will compile the  resources/assets/sass/app.scss SASS file. This app.scss file imports a file of SASS variables and loads Bootstrap, which provides a good starting point for most applications. Feel free to customize the app.scss file however you wish or even use an entirely different pre-processor by configuring Laravel Mix.

How do I include the `app.scss` file.  i.e. -- if this were an `app.css`, I'd like link it in the head of my document.  However, as its an `app.scss` file, the browser won't understand it natively (or will it?) and I'm not sure how Larval expects us to insert this into the page.

Comment: app.scss will be compiled to public/assets/app.css using laravel mix, but you still you have to manually add the file to the page.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi Re: "manually add the file to the page" -- does Laravel have methods/APIs for this -- or is the intent to use a link tag.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Answer (score 4):

After building your assets with something like `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, you'll get a plain old `app.css` file somewhere in your `public` tree.  After that, a little

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
```

in your blade templates and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use `app.scss` you need to compile scss file to css and move the compiled file to public directory in your Laravel project root.

Where you store compiled css is up to you, most people store css in `public/css/app.css`

There are several automation tools you can use to compile app.scss such as **Laravel mix, gulpjs, grunt** etc.

To learn more about compiling scss files start here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

However,  you mustn't go through all these processes in order to use Bootstrap in Laravel blade

Simply move bootstrap files (css,js) to Laravel `public` directory and use then like so in your blade template.

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{assets('css/bootsrap.css')}}" />
</head>
```